# EF Core 3.0 .Include does not work as expected and Super Slow

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.0

I have linq query like this in EF Core 2.0, It work as it is, but when I upgrade to EF Core 3.0 it always timeout. I found the issue in `query = query.Where(x => x.Questions);`.
My Question is i would like to return the course with filter questions like only Take(10) or with .Where condition that only display certain range not all questions.

```
var query = _courseRepository.Table;
query = query.Where(x => x.Id == id);
query = query.Include(x => x.Questions);
query = query.Include(x => x.CourseYear);
query = query.Include(x => x.CourseSubject);
query = query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.User);
query = query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.Course);
query = query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.CourseClass);
query = query.Include(x => x.CourseSections);
query = query.Include(x => x.CourseSections).ThenInclude(y => y.Lessons);
query = query.Include(x => x.CourseClasses);
query = query.Include(x => x.UserCourses).ThenInclude(y => y.User);
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please use a SQL Trace to get the SQL being executed by 2.2. Then do the same for 3.0. Please share both of them in your question.

Comment: `I found the issue in query = query.Where(x => x.Questions);.` That code is not in your question.

Comment: I would like to know how to return include questions with condition, cause I try few way It always return all list.

Comment: It looks like you're using `.Include` for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. You shouldn't use it for that - you should only use `.Include()` for zero-or-one-to-one or many-to-one relationships.

Comment: @Dai from the EF Docs is permit this .Include for one to many, what you means you should n't use it.

Comment: Wait for efcore 5, it suppose to solve this issue, I keep my 2.2 version till then.

Answer (score 8):

EFCore 3.0 changed the query(ies) generated by using `.Include()` and you are experiencing the *Cartesian Explosion Problem*;

Specifically there is the following Red Caution in the Docs now:

> Caution
>
> Since version 3.0.0, each Include will cause an additional JOIN to be
>   added to SQL queries produced by relational providers, whereas
>   previous versions generated additional SQL queries. This can
>   significantly change the performance of your queries, for better or
>   worse. In particular, LINQ queries with an exceedingly high number of
>   Include operators may need to be broken down into multiple separate
>   LINQ queries in order to avoid the cartesian explosion problem.

The solution is to execute multiple queries now per the docs.

Its super unfortunate loading entity graphs, common to highly normalized data, is so un-performant but this is its current state with EF.

See: Loading [Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) and scroll until you see red.

Comment: Efcore3 slowed down my app I had to revert it back yo 2.2

Comment: @OffirPe'er Same here. This is really unfortunate. I don't get why the EF team wouldn't at least give us an option to change this behavior.

Comment: @SebastianBrandesKraaijenzank In EF-Core 5 they will have this option, but I won't take any chance with them for now

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = _courseRepository.Table
.Include(x => x.Questions)
.Include(x => x.CourseClasses)
.Include(x => x.CourseYear)
.Include(x => x.CourseSubject);

var course = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.User).SelectMany(a => a.Instructors).Load();
query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.Course).SelectMany(a => a.Instructors).Load();
query.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.CourseClass).SelectMany(a => a.Instructors).Load();

query.Include(x => x.CourseSections).ThenInclude(y => y.Lessons).SelectMany(a => a.CourseSections).Load();

query.Include(x => x.UserCourses).ThenInclude(y => y.User).SelectMany(a => a.UserCourses).Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case, i had entities with multiple cardinalities and EF was building a query with many left joins causing a cartesian explosion.

I fixed using AsSplitQuery() at the end of my Includes that generate an additional SQL query for each included collection navigation

In your case it will be something like this:

```
var query = _courseRepository.Table
.Where(x => x.Id == id)
.Include(x => x.Questions)
.Include(x => x.CourseYear)
.Include(x => x.CourseSubject)
.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.User)
.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.Course)
.Include(x => x.Instructors).ThenInclude(y => y.CourseClass)
.Include(x => x.CourseSections)
.Include(x => x.CourseSections).ThenInclude(y => y.Lessons)
.Include(x => x.CourseClasses)
.Include(x => x.UserCourses).ThenInclude(y => y.User).AsSplitQuery()
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Read this documentation for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries